# Oracle and angle brackets

Tags: c#, xml, oracle

Just wondering what would be the cause of the problem that I experience in XML.

I create an element with the following inner text in C#:

```
  XmlElement a_ioad = pdb.CreateElement("A_IOAD");
  a_ioad.InnerText = "<Device>:<Device>_00";
```

When I save the XML document, left brackets become & lt; and right become & gt; which is right.
Then I import the xml file into Oracle database (through calling stored procedure or directly loading file via SQL Developer). For some weird reason all inner text right brackets > change from & gt; to '>' which invalidates the syntax.

What am I doing wrong? How do I troubleshoot it?

Comment: I would use [`InnerXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innerxml.aspx) instead.

Comment: What do you mean by 'loading' ? Did you insert it into database table? If yes, please specify field type. Of course, better variant is to post Oracle code used to handle that XML parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was down to encoding of the document (in XML declaration). In my instance it should have been utf-16 and not utf-8.